# DB2 XML query not producing expected XML output

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I'm having some trouble outputting XML data (in DB2) with the right XML structure.

Here's an example of the result of a query with a WHERE clause that would be something like WHERE InvoiceNumber IN (‘383’, '385') … the result is 5 rows

```
Inv# InvoiceDate InvoiceAmt  Warehouse  GLAccount PostDate    GLAmount
383  20140526    391         02         020       20170526    72
383  20140526    391         02         030       20170526    252
383  20140526    391         02         040       20170526    67
385  20140527    324         02         020       20170526    72
385  20140527    324         02         030       20170526    252
```

The first three rows, because they are the same invoice number (i.e. 383) should result in 1 invoice tag (shown in the below XML). The last two rows should result in another invoice tag (shown in the below XML).

That invoice tag contains a Header tag that contains all of the header fields (i.e. common values between the 3 rows such as Inv#, Invoice Date, Invoice Amount and Warehouse number).

The invoice tag also contains detail tags, which each have 3 rows (i.e. Account, Post Date and Detailed Amount).

So, the XML structure should look like this...

```
<Register> 002764
    <Invoice>
              <Header>
                   <InvoiceType>RI</InvoiceType>
                   <Inv#>383</Inv#>
                   <InvoiceDate>20170526</InvoiceDate>
                   <InvoiceAmount>391</InvoiceAmount>
                   <Warehouse>ICE01</Warehouse>
              </Header>
              <Detail>
                   <GLAccount>020</GLAccount>
                   <DetailedAmount>72</DetailedAmount>
                   <PostDate>20170501</PostDate>
              </Detail>
              <Detail>
                   <Account>030</Account>
                   <DetailedAmount>252</DetailedAmount>
                   <PostDate>20170526</PostDate>
              </Detail>
              <Detail>
                   <Account>040</Account>
                   <DetailedAmount>267</DetailedAmount>
                   <PostDate>20170526</PostDate>
              </Detail>
    </Invoice>

    <Invoice>
      <Header>
           <InvoiceType>RI</InvoiceType>
           <InvoiceNumber>385</InvoiceNumber>
           <InvoiceDate>20170527</InvoiceDate>
           <InvoiceAmount>324</InvoiceAmount>
           <Warehouse>02</Warehouse>
      </Header>
      <Detail>
           <GlAccount>020</GlAccount>
           <GlAmount>72</GlAmount>
           <PostingDate>20170526</PostingDate>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
           <GlAccount>030</GlAccount>
           <GlAmount>252</GlAmount>
           <PostingDate>20170526</PostingDate>
      </Detail>
   </Invoice>
</Register>
```

I'm trying to get the Register tag to fully enclose all the invoice tags to  produce the exact XML format shown above.

The code outputs a register tag separately, instead of having the register tag enclose all invoices. Like this..

```
    <Register>002764</Register>

    <Invoice>
          <Header>
               <InvoiceType>RI</InvoiceType>
               <Inv#>383</Inv#>
               <InvoiceDate>20170526</InvoiceDate>
               <InvoiceAmount>391</InvoiceAmount>
               <Warehouse>ICE01</Warehouse>
          </Header>
          <Detail>
               <GLAccount>020</GLAccount>
               <DetailedAmount>72</DetailedAmount>
               <PostDate>20170501</PostDate>
          </Detail>
          <Detail>
               <Account>030</Account>
               <DetailedAmount>252</DetailedAmount>
               <PostDate>20170526</PostDate>
          </Detail>
          <Detail>
               <Account>040</Account>
               <DetailedAmount>267</DetailedAmount>
               <PostDate>20170526</PostDate>
          </Detail>
    </Invoice>

    <Invoice>
      <Header>
           <InvoiceType>RI</InvoiceType>
           <InvoiceNumber>385</InvoiceNumber>
           <InvoiceDate>20170527</InvoiceDate>
           <InvoiceAmount>324</InvoiceAmount>
           <Warehouse>02</Warehouse>
      </Header>
      <Detail>
           <GlAccount>020</GlAccount>
           <GlAmount>72</GlAmount>
           <PostingDate>20170526</PostingDate>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
           <GlAccount>030</GlAccount>
           <GlAmount>252</GlAmount>
           <PostingDate>20170526</PostingDate>
      </Detail>
   </Invoice>
```

Here is my DB2 code..

```
SELECT
--XMLDOCUMENT(
--  XMLELEMENT(NAME "Receivables",
--      XMLFOREST(''P1'' AS CompanyCode),
--      XMLELEMENT(NAME "Register", IPGL_001),
        XMLELEMENT ( NAME "Invoice",
            XMLELEMENT ( NAME "Header",
                XMLFOREST(
                        'RI' as InvoiceType,
                        trim(IPGL_002) AS InvoiceNumber, 
                        IPGL_007 AS InvoiceDate,
                        SUM(IPGL_005) AS InvoiceAmount,
--                      trim(CLIENT_119) AS ExternalClientCode,
--                      trim(CLIENT_002) as ClientName,
--                      CLIENT_003 AS ClientAddress1,
--                      CLIENT_004 AS ClientAddress2,
--                      trim(CLIENT_005) AS ClientAddress3,
--                      CLIENT_006 AS ClientAddress4,
                        WHSE AS Warehouse   
                ) -- end of forest
            ) -- end of header
            , (SELECT XMLAgg (XMLELEMENT (NAME "Detail", 
                                                XMLFOREST (TRIM(IPGL_004) AS "GLAccount",
                                                            IPGL_005 AS "GLAmount", 
                                                            IPGL_003 AS "PostingDate"
                                                            ) -- END OF XMLFOREST
                                            ) -- END OF XMLELEMENT DETAIL
                                ) -- END OF XMLAgg
                FROM PW_IPGL_L1 AS DTL WHERE DTL.IPGL_002=IPGL.IPGL_002)
        ) -- end of invoice
--  ) -- end of Receivables root element
--) -- end of XMLDOCUMENT
FROM PW_IPGL_L1 AS IPGL
JOIN PW_CLIENT_L1 AS CLIENT
    ON IPGL.IPGL_006 = CLIENT.CLIENT_001
JOIN (
    SELECT RERH_002 AS InvoiceNumber, RERH_031 AS WHSE FROM PW_RERH_L1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ACC1_002 AS InvoiceNumber, ACC1_017 AS WHSE FROM PW_ACC1_L1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REC1_002 AS InvoiceNumber, REC1_018 AS WHSE FROM PW_REC1_L1
) AS INVOICES
    ON IPGL.IPGL_002 = INVOICES.InvoiceNumber
WHERE IPGL_002 IN ('151125 ', '151124 ')

GROUP BY IPGL_001, IPGL_002, IPGL_007, WHSE
ORDER BY IPGL_002;
```

Comment: The element names in your query and the sample doc do not match. You need to adapt it. Also add the doc your query produces for debugging.

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik, I will do so now.